# how to make an (load)image overlay a panel

Tags: java, gwt

In my app i have some interactive widgets but while loading data from server this widgets must be inactivated and activated again after loading is complete. i don't want to make the widgets invisible or inactivate every single field/button. 
the best solution would be a transparent panel with an loading image in its center or corner overlaying the widgets while loading - but how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some simple code to start with. I have used it in some application but it was with GWT 2.0, maybe they got something better now. You could probably replace the Label with an animated Gif image and simply add the panel to the root panel should do the trick.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimplePanel;

public class GlassPanel extends SimplePanel implements NativePreviewHandler {

    private Label text;

    public GlassPanel() {
        setStyleName("glass-panel");
        add(text = new Label());
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        event.consume();
        event.cancel();
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.glass-panel {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    z-index: 4000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thx!
i guess that the event handler implementation is the part of deactivating the user interactions?

Comment: If I remember correctly it stops all events that are on the glasspanel so that it prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the widgets under the panel. You may have to adjust bits and pieces here and there but it gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to add 'mozOpacity', also in addition to 'opacity' and 'filter' (or is that obsolete now? just adding my two cents worth)

Comment: i voted up your two cents - i think you need some reputation ;-)